# How to generate 2 non-adjacent random numbers in a range

Tags: algorithm, random

I need to generate 2 random numbers in a range [A..B] with the restriction that the numbers can not be adjacent. 
I would like to do it in constant time (I don't want to keep drawing until the 2nd value is good).

I can think of several ways to do this:

- Pick the first, then pick one that fits after it: Draw V1 from the range `[A..B-2]`, then draw V2 from the range `[V1+2..B]`
- Pick the distance between them, then place them: Draw d from `[2..B-A]` and V1 from `[0..B-A-d]` then `V2=V1+d`
- Pick the first, then pick an offset to the second one: Draw V1 from the whole range, then draw d from the range `[A+2-V1..B-V1-1]`, and set `V2= d<=0 ? V1-2+d : V1+1+d`
- Pick the first, then pick the distance to the second with wrapping:  pick V1 from `[A..B]`, d from `[0..A-B-2]`,  `V2 = V1+d`; `V2 = V2>B ? V2-(B-A)`

I want the most random method (generates most entropy, has most even distribution).  I think the last 2 are equivalent and more random than the first two.  Is there an even better way?

Comment: Nothing wrong with redrawing by the way - that's how you ensure uniform distribution when your range isn't a power of 2. Your random number function is probably already doing it without your being aware.

Comment: The fourth method you suggest seems the most natural and easiest to prove properties of.

Comment: Is `V1 == V2` allowed?

Comment: Is `A` adjacent to `B`? Is it "cycle" range?

Comment: For the purposes of discussion, A and B are at least 4 units apart.  The range does not wrap.  V1 can not equal V2.

Comment: @Mark Ransom, I really want to avoid redrawing b/c the random source is essentially a one-time pad. I can't risk running out of "pulls".

Answer (score 4):

Assume that the range is `[0, n)`. For random unordered nonadjacent pairs, it suffices to generate a random unordered pair from `[0, n-2)` and increase the greater element by `2`. The latter can be accomplished by a bijective mapping from `[0, (n+1)n/2)`.

```
import random


def randnonadjpair(n):
    i, j = randunordpair(n-2)
    return i, j+2


def randunordpair(n):
    i = random.randrange((n+1)*n//2)
    if n%2 == 1:
        if i < n:
            return i, n-1
        i -= n
        n -= 1
    h = n//2
    q, r = divmod(i, h)
    if q < h:
        return q, h + r
    q -= h
    if q <= r:
        return q, r
    return n-q, n-1-r
```

---

(This answer is for ordered pairs.)

There are `2 (n-2) + (n-2) (n-3) = n^2 - 3 n + 2` ways to choose two ordered nonadjacent elements from a range of length `n`. Generate a random number `x` between `0` inclusive and `n^2 - 3 n + 2` exclusive and then map it bijectively to a valid outcome:

```
def biject(n, x):
    if x < n - 2:
        return (0, x + 2)
    x -= n - 2
    if x < n - 2:
        return (n - 1, x)
    x -= n - 2
    q, r = divmod(x, n - 3)
    return (q, r if r < q - 1 else r + 3)
```

Comment: I get half your number of possibilites:  for 5 elements, there are 6 valid combinations, not 12, right?

Comment: @AShelly If you meant unordered pairs, then yes.

Comment: @AShelly Added the unordered version.

Answer (score 2):

If you want maximum entropy then your two picks have to be independent.  Thus the value of the second pick cannot be limited by the first pick; both have to be chosen from the entire range available.  That means picking the two numbers independently, checking them as a pair and rejecting both if the pair is unsuitable.  In pseudocode, that looks something like:

```
function pickPair()
  repeat
    num1 <- random(A, B)
    num2 <- random(A, B)
  until (notAdjacent(num1, num2))
  return (num1, num2)
end function
```

You check the constraints on the two numbers in the method `notAdjacent()`.

You do not state the size of the range [A..B].  Given a reasonably large range then the chances of having to reject a pair are low. Alternatively, always pick a fixed number of pairs and return any of the pairs that matches your criterion:

```
function constantTimePickPair
  pairFound <- false
  repeats <- 5 // Or enough to ensure certainty of a valid pair.
  do repeats times
    num1 <- random(A, B)
    num2 <- random(A, B)
    if (notAdjacent(num1, num2))
      pairFound <- true
      result <- (num1, num2)
    end if
  end do

  if (NOT pairFound)
    throw error "Pair not found."
  end if

  return result
end function
```

You will need to set enough repeats to make statistically certain of finding a valid pair.

Comment: I was working on my own answer, but after thinking about what you said I believe this is the only true way. It's useful to think about the case [1..5]; there are 25 different combinations, but only 12 of them are valid. The odds of picking any single combination *must* be 1 in 12, or the results won't be evenly distributed. If you choose V1 without restriction, each value has a 1 in 5 chance, and since 5 does not divide evenly into 12 it's *impossible* to get uniform distribution on V2.

Comment: @MarkRansom second distribution is not even because a choice to pick extreme elements is higher than a choice to pick an inner element.

Comment: @fl00r of the 12 valid combinations for [1..5], 3 are (1,x) and 2 are (2,x). If you have the same odds of V1=1 or V1=2, you *will* have an uneven distribution.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I would do it as follows:</strike>

- Draw `V1` from [A..B]
- If `V1 == A || V1 == B` draw `V2` from [A..B-1], else draw `V2` from [A..B-2]
- Do:

  ```
  if(V2 >= V1 - 1) V2++;
  if(V2 >= V1 + 1) V2++;
  ```

The first check makes sure that `V1 - 1` can not be the value of `V2`
The second check makes sure that `V1 + 1` can not be the value of `V2`.
Or, in other words, this remaps the values to [A..V1-2][V1][V1+2..B].

Since this does not discard nor repeat any values, the distribution should be good.

This answer currently assumes `V1 == V2` is valid.

---

In fact, no, the distribution of the above would be biased.
If `N = B - A + 1`,

- for a number `= A` or `= B`, there are `N - 2` pairs containing it
- for a number in `[A+1...B-1]`, there are only `N - 3` pairs containing it.

Calculate the number of pairs `M`, draw a number in `[1..M]` and map it back to the corresponding pair, as detailed for example in David Eisenstats answer.

Comment: If (V1==A) or (V1==B) there is only one adjacent

Comment: The formulation of the question is not precise, but I'm not expecting that getting two identical values (which are not adjacent) is what was intended.

Comment: @JimD. That's not how I understood it, I'll ask the OP. If that's true, it's even simpler: Draw V2 from [A..B-3] and do `if(V2 >= V1 - 1) V2 += 3` (plus special cases)

Answer (score 0):

How about the following approach:

```
V1 = rand(A..B)
V2 = rand(A+2..B-1)
V2 += V2 > V1 ? 1 : -2
```

Also, it should be mentioned that you can't get an even distribution here for the second choice.

Border items on the left and on the right will have slightly more chances to be picked.

The probability for inner numbers is `(B-A-3)/(B-A)`, while probability for border elements is `(B-A-2)/(B-A)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my current plan:

Given target range `[A..B]`. It's length `L` is `A-B+1`.  We want to choose `V1,V2` such that `V2` is not in range `[V1-1..V1+1]`
If `V1` is `A`, then there are `L-2` possibilities for `V2`
If `V1` is `A+1`, there are `L-3` possibilities for `V2`.
...
Extending this pattern, we get the total number of possibilities `P` as `sum([1..L-2])`.  *(This is half the number @David Eisenstat came up with).*

If we pick a number `N` in the range `[0,P)`, then we can generate the corresponding combination with:

```
V1 = A
T = L-2
while (N >= T):
   N -= T
   T -= 1
   V1 += 1
V2 = V2 + N + 2
```

Comment: You get half the possibilities because he considers (1,3) and (3,1) to be different but you consider them to be the same. Is your uniformity requirement based on them being the same?

Comment: I consider them to be the same.